# Local DNS for AWS instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, hostname

Amazon provides a domain names like `blah-blah.amazonaws.com`.  They want us to use the domain name instead of an IP because the IPs are transient.

The local hosts file on my computer only takes IP addresses.
So, how can I redirect `dev.example.com` to `blah-blah.amazonaws.com` locally from my machine?

Comment: Why do you need to do this on your local hosts file? Can you create a DNS entry?

Comment: what is your computer? And what are you trying to access?  Something in public dns or private ??

Answer (score 1):

In the DNS zone for for `example.com` you create a `cname` record of `dev`, pointing to `blah-blah.amazonaws.com.` (the trailing dot in the URL is *very* important).